# INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns won't list two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code which is supposed to display the column name, data type, size, # of filled columns and the total rows.

The problem that I am running into is that using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns` I can only display either `DATA_TYPE` or `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH`. If I try to `SELECT` both I get errors:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'si'.

The code statement is:

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(512) = 'state';
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1024);

WITH SQLText AS (
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.Name) AS RowNum,
    'SELECT ''' + c.name + ''', 
    MAX(b.DATA_TYPE) AS ''Data Type'', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ' + c.Name + ' IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS ''Filled Values'', 
    COUNT(*) AS ''Total Records'' 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns b 
    JOIN ' + @TableName + ' ON b.column_name = ''' + c.name +'''' AS SQLRow
FROM 
    sys.tables t 
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    JOIN sys.types a ON c.user_type_id = a.user_type_id
WHERE 
    t.name = @TableName)
```

Any ideas on how to get both to display?

Comment: You mention a problem with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, and yet your query uses `sys` instead.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the constructed query `SQLRow` uses `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for some reason.

Comment: Can you add the SQL that causes the error? that is the working SQL I think.

Comment: My first thought is you could probably use an outer apply, because you expanding out the records in info schema you're having to use max which is just messy.

Comment: Your query executes without errors, please clarify the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(512) = 'Settings';
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1024);

WITH SQLText AS (
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.Name) AS RowNum,
    'SELECT ''' + c.name + ''', 
    MAX(b.DATA_TYPE) AS ''Data Type'', 
    Max(b.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH) as ''CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH'',
    SUM(CASE WHEN ' + c.Name + ' IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS ''Filled Values'', 
    COUNT(*) AS ''Total Records'' 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns b 
    JOIN ' + @TableName + ' ON b.column_name = ''' + c.name +'''' AS SQLRow
FROM 
    sys.tables t 
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    JOIN sys.types a ON c.user_type_id = a.user_type_id
WHERE 
    t.name = @TableName)

    select * from SQLText
```

This works for me, tbh though i'd add to get a better idea of the size a column uses.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ' + c.Name + ' IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Datalength(' + c.Name + ') END) AS ''Filled Values'',
```

Comment: Did you change anything from the original query, or just confirming it works?  OP query executes without modification.

Comment: added the column he asked to be added to the SQL it generates.  The SQL the query generates also works.  It seems to be a report on which columns have data and how large that data could be.

Comment: Sorry, my original code works fine, it is when I insert the `MAX(b.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH)` that the error appears.`

Comment: @TaiwanTimmy which the query above has.

Comment: When I ran this, it responded with:
`Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'Data'.`
and
`Incorrect syntax near 'Data'.`

Comment: mmm ok - works on SQL2014 cut and pasted from this page, what version of SQL and have you changed what is above?